# Replacing/Removing paranthetical comments in a TEXT FILE using python

Tags: python, text

I am trying to remove all parenthetical comments that are in a **text** file. Here is an very brief example called "sample.txt":

> Sentence one (comment 1). Second sentence (second comment).

I would like it to look like this instead:

> Sentence one . Second sentence .

I have tried re.sub in the form below, but can only get it to work for strings, **not text files**. Here one of the many things I've tried:

```
intext = 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\sample.txt'
outtext = 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\EDITEDsample.txt'
with open(intext, 'r') as f, open(outtext, 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write(re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', ''))
```

This doesn't get me an error message but it also doesn't do anything to the text.

```
with open (intext, 'r') as f, open(outtext, 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write(line.replace('(', " ").replace(')', " "))
```

This successfully removes the parenthesis, but since .replace doesn't handle regex, I don't see how I can use it to also remove any text that is between parenthesis.

I also tried

```
with open (intext, 'r') as f, open(outtext, 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', outtext)
```

but I get an error saying I'm missing a string, which is expected since re.sub requires strings. What can I use to remove/replace parenthetical comments from a **TEXT file**?

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` takes three parameters (pattern, replacement, string), and the result must be assigned back to a variable:

```
import re

# Read entire file as a string into a variable
with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

# Replace all parenthesized items.
# Make sure to use a non-greedy match or it will replace everything
# from the very first parenthesis to the very last parenthesis.
# Note that this will NOT handle nested parentheses correctly,
# e.g. "a (commented (nested)) sentence" -> "a ) sentence".
# Regular expressions don't handle nesting well.  Use a parser for that.
data = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)','',data)

# write file back out
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Input file:

```
sentence (comment) sentence (comment)
sentence (comment) sentence (comment)
sentence (comment) sentence (comment)
```

Output file:

```
sentence  sentence
sentence  sentence
sentence  sentence
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, this did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with regular expression is that you can't handle nested parentheses.
something like "(())" is bound to fail.

So assuming each '(' is followed by an ')', It would be better if you could handle it this way :

```
infile = ["Sentence one (comment 2). Second sentence (second comment).\n",
          "Sentence one (comment 2). Second sentence (second (comment)((((((())))))))."]

open_parenthese_counter = 0

for line in infile:
    for char in line:
        if open_parenthese_counter == 0:
            print(char, end='') # write into the output file.
        elif char == '(':
            open_parenthese_counter += 1
        elif char == ')':
            open_parenthese_counter -= 1  # = max(open_parenthese_counter-1, 0)
```

and then make changes as u see fits.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Sentence one . Second sentence .
Sentence one . Second sentence .
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the newer `regex` module with

```
\((?:[^()]+|(?R))+\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Kcf3Ic/1/).

---

In `Python` this could be

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile(r'\((?:[^()]+|(?R))+\)')

data = """


    Sentence one (comment 1). Second sentence (second comment).

    Or even ((nested) ones).
"""

data = rx.sub('', data)
```